# Return a 404 when a view pane in a page manager page has no result?

Tags: views, panels

When you have a view page that takes a contextual filter, you can easily set the no result behavior to a 404. But I am trying to do this when I have a view pane, in a page manager page like in the screenshot attached[image]

If the view has no result (contextual fitter does not validate) I would like the page to return a 404.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) in your module to do this task

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
 function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
   if ($view->name == 'myview' && $view->current_display == 'mypane') {
     if (empty($view->result)) {
       drupal_not_found();
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew's answer adopted to Drupal 8:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if (
            array_key_exists('title', $view->build_info)
            && $view->build_info['title'] == 'My View'
            && $view->current_display == 'mypane'
    ) {
        if (empty($view->result)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
    }
}
```